# Command line to send email if CPU load is high

Tags: shell-script, email

I want to write a one liner on the terminal to send email if cpu load is high. I have this one but its send everytime its run

```
while true; do
  lsof -u nagios | wc -l;
  b=15;
  a=$(uptime | awk '{print $10}' | cut -d ',' -f1);
  uptime;
  if echo $a $b | awk '{exit $1>$2?0:1}'; then
    echo "DAL MCOM Nagios Load" | mailx -s "Load is greater than 15 $a" hai.le@xxx;
   fi;
   sleep 10;
done
```

I want to do this on the terminal

Comment: Don't write “one liners” than span several lines. If it's more than 80 characters long, it isn't a one-liner.

Comment: thxs for ur suggestion Gilles

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you want an email if load is 3 or higher:

```
max=3; load=$(cat /proc/loadavg | cut -d' ' -f1); [[ "${load%.*}" -ge "$max" ]] && mail -s "Load exceeded $max on $(hostname -s)" username@example.com
```

Comment: Lets me test this out, thxs Dope